# Eisov not wearing his best clothes for Yitzhak's blessing?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, parashat-toldot

1. Eisov wore his best suit (*the "royal robe" he took from Nimrod, who took it from Adam etc*) whenever he served his father Itzhok (Bereishis Rabboh 65, 16). He kept it by his mother Rivkah's:

> "וַתִּקַּח רִבְקָה אֶת בִּגְדֵי עֵשָׂו בְּנָהּ הַגָּדֹל הַחֲמֻדֹת אֲשֶׁר אִתָּהּ בַּבָּיִת" (בראשית כז טו) – שבהם היה משמש את אביו. אמר ר' שמעון בן גמליאל: כל ימי הייתי משמש את אבא ולא שמשתי אותו אחד ממאה ששמש עשו את אביו. אני בשעה שהייתי משמש את אבא, הייתי משמשו בבגדים מלוכלכים; ובשעה שהייתי יוצא לדרך, הייתי יוצא בבגדים נקיים. אבל עשו, **בשעה שהיה משמש את אביו, לא היה משמשו אלא בבגדי מלכות. אמר: אין כבודו של אבא להיות משמשו, אלא בבגדי מלכות**."
>
> *my translation in short: R' Shimon Ben Gamliel says ... [we learn from this Pasuk that] Eisov served his father with his best and special clothes.*

2. To disguise Yaakov, Rivka made him wear this robe. Later, Yitzhok smelled it to be convinced he's Eisov.
3. When Eisov comes back from hunting he prepares the food and enters Yitzhok's room, with "revolving doors", as Yaakov leaves ("יצוא יצא" ibid).

*Now, freeze and rewind*, For his most important ceremony, Eisov forgets to wear his best suit, he does not question his mother where it is.

Do the interpreters address this inconsistency?

Comment: Perhaps Esav was concerned when Yitzhak said at the beginning of his request "I don't know the day I shall die." Maybe that made him hurry.

Comment: Where do you see that Yaakov didn’t have a chance to put the clothing back for Esav to put on before he returned?

Comment: @DonielF #3 same Midrash (I think Rashi says it in place) - יצוא יצא - revolving doors - Yaakov leaves, Eisov enters simultaneously.

Comment: Esav only then came in from the hunt (v. 30). He still had to make the "tasty foods" for his father, before going in to see him (v. 31). That should have been time enough for Ya'aqov to return the suit to his mother.

Comment: @TamirEvan you miss Rashi's interpretation of יצוא יצא.

Comment: ... which is on the verse **before** the one that says "ויעש גם הוא מטעמים וַיָּבֵא לאביו" (v. 31). No, I didn't miss that Rashi (on v. 30). You seem to have missed that Esav did something between "ויהי אך **יָצֹא יָצָא** יעקב מאת פני יצחק אביו ועשו אחיו בא מצידו" (v.30) and "וַיָּבֵא לאביו" (v.31).

Comment: @AlBerko Thanks for bolding the words **משמש את אביו** in [*Bereishit Rabbah*](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.65.16?lang=bi) 65:16. It helped me find the quote in the [*Pesikta Rabbasi*](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.23.1?lang=bi) 24:58 that was cited on page 441 of [*Ishei Hatanach*](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899060255.html):

"When [Eisav] served his father, he [wore] royal robes"